# Uso de Map, Listas, Conjuntos, etc

Tags: java, lista, map, conjuntos

estoy estudiando java a distancia, y estamos dando ahora el tema de Listas, Conjuntos, etc y estoy bastante perdido con el tema y agradecería un poquito de ayuda porque no doy con el.
Me piden el siguiente ejercicio y no se por donde cogerlo.

> Paso 3.- Crear el método noLaborable
>
> Este método es un poco más complejo que el anterior. Aceptará una
>   fecha como parámetro, pero retornará todos los intervalos de fechas en
>   los que es no laborable (solo retornará los nombres de los
>   intervalos). Veamos:
>
> Será un método público. Aceptará como parámetro una instancia de
>   LocalDate. Esa fecha corresponderá con la fecha a verificar. Retornará
>   un conjunto de cadenas de texto que contendrá el nombre de todos los
>   intervalos de fechas en los que dicha fecha es no laborable. Puede
>   ocurrir que una fecha coincida con dos o más periodos no laborables.
>   Por ejemplo, si te fijas en el conjunto de intervalos de fechas
>   creados en el método buildSampleAgenda, la fecha "2019-12-06" es no
>   laborable porque coincide con los intervalos llamados PUENTEDIC
>   (puente de diciembre) y con MERECIDASVACACIONES. En ese caso, para la
>   agenda de prueba, este método debe retornar un conjunto que incluya
>   las cadenas "PUENTEDIC" y "MERECIDASVACACIONES".
>
> Importante: fíjate que la clase IntervaloFechas incluye un método
>   llamado estaDentroDelIntervalo que aquí te puede ser de mucha
>   utilidad.
>
> Una vez realizado esto, ya puedes ejecutar TareaUT8Paso3 y comprobar
>   si sale el resultado esperado.

```
public class Agenda {

/**
 * Cantidad maxima de citas que puede tener una agenda en un mismo dia para cualquier agenda
 */
public static int MAX_CITAS_DIA_CUALQUIER_AGENDA = 40;

/**
 * Cantidad minima de citas que debe tener una agenda en un mismo dia para cualquier agenda.
 */
public static int MIN_CITAS_DIA_CUALQUIER_AGENDA = 5;

/**
 * Cantidad maxima de citas que puede tener la agenda asignada
 */
public static int MAX_CITAS_DIA;

/**
 * Nombre de la agenda
 */
public static String nomAgenda;

public List <Cita> listaCitas = new LinkedList<Cita>();
public Set<DayOfWeek> noHabiles = new HashSet<DayOfWeek>();
public HashMap<String, IntervaloFechas> noLaborables;
public IntervaloFechas intervaloFechas;

public Agenda(String nombreAgenda, int maximoCitas, Set diasNoHabiles, HashMap diasNoLaborables) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if (nombreAgenda == null){
        this.nomAgenda = "DEFAULT";
    }else{
        this.nomAgenda = nombreAgenda;
    }

    if (maximoCitas > MAX_CITAS_DIA_CUALQUIER_AGENDA || maximoCitas < MIN_CITAS_DIA_CUALQUIER_AGENDA){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("El numero de citas no esta comprendido entre los valores maximo y minimo permitidos");
    }else{
        this.MAX_CITAS_DIA = maximoCitas;
    }

    if (diasNoHabiles != null){
        this.noHabiles = diasNoHabiles;
    }

    if(diasNoLaborables != null){
        this.noLaborables = diasNoLaborables;
    }

}

public static Agenda buildSampleAgenda(){
    Set<DayOfWeek> noHabiles = new HashSet<DayOfWeek>();
    noHabiles.add(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY);
    noHabiles.add(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);

    HashMap<String, IntervaloFechas> noLaborable = new HashMap<String, IntervaloFechas>();
    noLaborable.put("SEMANASANTA", IntervaloFechas.of(2020,4,4,2020,4,12));
    noLaborable.put("PUENTEDIC", IntervaloFechas.of(2019,12,5,2019,12,9));
    noLaborable.put("MERECIDASVACACIONES", IntervaloFechas.of(2019,11,3,2019,12,7));
    noLaborable.put("NAVIDADES", IntervaloFechas.of(2019,12,21,2020,1,7));
    noLaborable.put("PUENTENOV", IntervaloFechas.of(2019,11,1,2019,11,4));

    Agenda sample = new Agenda("SAMPLE", 10, noHabiles , noLaborable);

    Cliente[] clientes=Persona.buildSamplePersonas();

    Cita c1 = new Cita(clientes[0], LocalDateTime.parse("2019-02-19T20:00:00"), "Arreglar frigorífico.");
    Cita c2 = new Cita(clientes[1], LocalDateTime.parse("2019-02-19T18:00:00"), "Arreglar caldera.");
    Cita c3 = new Cita(clientes[2], LocalDateTime.parse("2019-02-19T17:00:00"), "Arreglar lavadora.");    
    Cita c4 = new Cita(clientes[3], LocalDateTime.parse("2019-02-19T21:00:00"), "Arreglar secador.");

    sample.listaCitas.add(c1);
    sample.listaCitas.add(c2);
    sample.listaCitas.add(c3);    
    sample.listaCitas.add(c4);


    return sample;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String cadena = "AGENDA: "+ Agenda.nomAgenda +"\n"
        + "Citas máximas por día: "+ Agenda.MAX_CITAS_DIA +"\n"
        + "Días no hábiles: "+ this.noHabiles +"\n"
        + "Rango de fechas no laborables:\n"
        + "..............................\n"
        + noLaborables.toString().replaceAll(",","\n").replaceAll("=", ": ");
    return cadena;
}

public boolean esDiaHabil (DayOfWeek diaSemana){
    if(noHabiles.contains(diaSemana)){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Dejo tambien el enlace a github por si quereis ver el proyecto entero:
https://github.com/Alexmysterio/Tarea-8

Gracias, Un Saludo

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a stackoverflow! En esta comunidad resolvemos dudas especificas, no hacemos tareas. Te invito a leer esto: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues cual es el problema que tienes en el código o que es lo que no entiendes.

Answer (score 0):

para hacer lo de los días no laborables debes hacer lo siguiente:

Debes declarar el método que devuelva un conjunto de nombres de periodos no laborables (String), y que reciba como parámetro un objeto Fecha, LocalDate.

Es decir, tienesque crear un conjunto local, de String, en el que irás añadiendo los periodos no laborables que contengan a la fecha recibida como parámetro y que será el que devolverás al final.

Paso 1. Declarar una variable local de tipo “Conjunto de String” en la que guardarás los nombres de todos los periodos no laborables que hay en el Mapa noLaborables. Para eso, el método keySet() es de gran ayuda. Llamémosle todosLosNoLaborables

Paso 2. Declarar la variable local de tipo “Conjunto de String” que usarás para componer la lista. Llamémosle noLaborablesQueIncluyenFecha

Paso 3. Recorre con un ciclo for-each todos los elementos del conjunto todosLosNoLaborables

Paso 3.1. Comprueba si el elemento que estás visitando en cada iteración contiene la fecha recigida como parámetro. Para eso, obtén del mapa NoLaborables el intervalo de fechas cuyo nombre coincida con el que estás visitando, (el método get es de gran ayuda) e invoca para ese intervalo el método estaDentroDelIntervalo definido en la clase IntervaloFechas, que es de gran ayuda.

Si lo está, añade el nombre del periodo al conjunto noLaborablesQueIncluyenFecha que devolverás al final.

Paso 4. Cuando salgas del bucle for, has recorrido todos los periodos no laborables, y has formado un conjunto con todos los que contienen la fecha. Solo te queda devolver ese conjunto con return.

Espero te sea útil.